# How to join two tables and group by ID and count in LINQ C# method syntax

Tags: c#, linq, linq-method-syntax

I have two tables:

```
PractitionerSkill { Id, Title }
PractitionerInSkills { Id, PractitionerSkillId ), where PractitionerSkillId is FK into PractitionerSkill
```

(there are more columns but that is not really important)

And I'm trying to count number of skills pr practitioner.

Using LINQ method syntax, I am trying to do this:

```
SELECT 
    S.Id, S.Title, COUNT(*) as [Count] from 
    PractitionerSkills S INNER JOIN 
    PractitionerInskills PIS ON S.ID = PIS.PractitionerSkillId
GROUP BY 
    S.Id, S.Title
ORDER BY
    S.Title
```

Easy in SQL. Notice that I'm getting the ID, title and count in the result.

My current efforts (which is not even method syntax)

```
var query = from skill in _context.PractitionerSkills
        join pis in _context.PractitionerInSkills on skill.Id equals pis.PractitionerSkillId into grp
        select new
        {
            Title = skill.Title,
            Count = grp.Count()
        };
```

which is almost there, but I can't get more columns out. I need the Skill.Id (or PractitionerInSkills.PractitionerSkillId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy in Linq too!

```
var query = _context.PractitionerSkills.Join(_context.PractitionerInSkills,
                                             ps => new { k1 = ps.Id },
                                             pis => new { k1 = pis.PractitionerSkillId },
                                             (ps, pis) => new { ps.Id, ps.Title })
                                       .GroupBy(r => new { r.Id, r.Title })
                                       .Select(g => new { g.Key.Id, g.Key.Title, Count = g.Count() })
                                       .OrderBy(r => r.Title);
```